# How to change matrix entries using conditional if in R

Tags: r, if-statement, matrix, conditional-statements, apply

I have this example matrix and I want to change the entries of the matrix with `"YES"` or `"NO"` based on a conditional `if` statement.

```
a<-c(5,1,0,3,2,0.6,1.6,7,9,0)
b<-c(11,0,1,18,11,11,0,13,20,10)
c<-c(10,20,0.7,0.8,0.3,0.4,0,0.9,1,1)

MAT<-cbind(a,b,c)
MAT

for (i in 1:nrow(MAT)){
  for (j in 1:ncol(MAT)){
  if (MAT[i,j]>5){
    MAT[i,j]="YES"
    } else {
    MAT[i,j]="NO"
    }
  }
}
print(MAT)
```

The output I got is like this and its wrong. Please help tell me what's wrong and how to fix it?

```
      a     b    c   
[1,] "NO"  "NO" "NO"
[2,] "NO"  "NO" "NO"
[3,] "NO"  "NO" "NO"
[4,] "NO"  "NO" "NO"
[5,] "NO"  "NO" "NO"
[6,] "NO"  "NO" "NO"
[7,] "NO"  "NO" "NO"
[8,] "YES" "NO" "NO"
[9,] "YES" "NO" "NO"
[10,] "NO"  "NO" "NO"
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You do not need loops here. Just use the whole matrix in your call to `x>5`

```
ifelse(MAT>5, "YES", "NO")
```

This will do the logical operation over the entire matrix, and output a logical matrix.

You can reassign the `VALUES` from the output of `ifelse()` while keeping the `STRUCTURE` of `MAT` by using the empty brackets `[]`, as in:

```
MAT[]<-ifelse(MAT>5, "YES", "NO")
```

Comment: It works well as I want and it is the simplest code among others so I accept this

Comment: Empty brackets after `MAT` are not necessary here because `ifelse` returns a value with the same shape as its `test` argument. Since `MAT>5` is a matrix, the value of `ifelse` will be a matrix as well.

Comment: Yes, you are right for this particular case, @Robert. But I think including the empty brackets is good practice here, as it is a more general approach that enforces the preservation of the class of the original data. Ifelse does return an object the same type of the 'test' argument. But the '<' is a function that coerces to a logical vector or matrix. If MAT was a data.frame, the empty brackets would be necessary, otherwise MAT would be coerced into a matrix.

Comment: @GuedesBF This is a good point, but in your answer you state that the output from `ifelse` would be a vector (a matrix stripped from its `dim` attribute) which is not true.

Comment: Yes, the answer included an innacurate statement, thanks for spoting that out, @Robert. I corrected the answer, considering your observations.

Answer (score 10):

## Reason of Failure

The reason you failed in your attempt comes from this part:

```
  if (MAT[i,j]>5){
    MAT[i,j]="YES"
    } else {
    MAT[i,j]="NO"
    }
  }
```

You should have be aware of that `MAT` is numerical, but you are assigning characters to `MAT` with in `if...else...` statement, which will make `MAT` converted to a character matrix. In this case, when you run `MAT[i,j] > 5`, you are comparing a character with a numeric value, e.g., `"18" > 5`, which returns an undesired `FALSE`.

---

## Workaround

A workaround is using another variable to store the values after `if...else...`, instead of replacing values in `MAT`:

```
a <- c(5, 1, 0, 3, 2, 0.6, 1.6, 7, 9, 0)
b <- c(11, 0, 1, 18, 11, 11, 0, 13, 20, 10)
c <- c(10, 20, 0.7, 0.8, 0.3, 0.4, 0, 0.9, 1, 1)

MAT <- cbind(a, b, c)
out <- MAT

for (i in 1:nrow(MAT)) {
  for (j in 1:ncol(MAT)) {
    if (MAT[i, j] > 5) {
      out[i, j] <- "YES"
    } else {
      out[i, j] <- "NO"
    }
  }
}
```

such that

```
> out
      a     b     c
 [1,] "NO"  "YES" "YES"
 [2,] "NO"  "NO"  "YES"
 [3,] "NO"  "NO"  "NO"
 [4,] "NO"  "YES" "NO"
 [5,] "NO"  "YES" "NO"
 [6,] "NO"  "YES" "NO"
 [7,] "NO"  "NO"  "NO"
 [8,] "YES" "YES" "NO"
 [9,] "YES" "YES" "NO"
[10,] "NO"  "YES" "NO"
```

---

## Alternative

There are already many answers to this question, and below is another base R option

```
> `dim<-`(as.character(factor(MAT > 5, labels = c("NO", "YES"))), dim(MAT))
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
 [1,] "NO"  "YES" "YES"
 [2,] "NO"  "NO"  "YES"
 [3,] "NO"  "NO"  "NO"
 [4,] "NO"  "YES" "NO"
 [5,] "NO"  "YES" "NO"
 [6,] "NO"  "YES" "NO"
 [7,] "NO"  "NO"  "NO"
 [8,] "YES" "YES" "NO"
 [9,] "YES" "YES" "NO"
[10,] "NO"  "YES" "NO"
```

Comment: For the alternative, it's also possible to write `structure(as.character(...), dim = dim(MAT))` or `array(as.character(...), dim = dim(MAT))`.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Yes, exactly.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut could you please check my post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68793463/reading-a-csv-file-as-matrix-and-change-the-entries-using-conditional-if-in-r/68794730#68794730 since it does not work when I use the codes inside the r function I made

Answer (score 5):

Using just logical matrix converted to numeric index

```
MAT[] <- c("NO", "YES")[1 + (MAT > 5)]
```

-ouptut

```
> MAT
      a     b     c    
 [1,] "NO"  "YES" "YES"
 [2,] "NO"  "NO"  "YES"
 [3,] "NO"  "NO"  "NO" 
 [4,] "NO"  "YES" "NO" 
 [5,] "NO"  "YES" "NO" 
 [6,] "NO"  "YES" "NO" 
 [7,] "NO"  "NO"  "NO" 
 [8,] "YES" "YES" "NO" 
 [9,] "YES" "YES" "NO" 
[10,] "NO"  "YES" "NO"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
apply(MAT, 2, function(x) ifelse(x > 5, "YES", "NO"))
```

```
      a     b     c    
 [1,] "NO"  "YES" "YES"
 [2,] "NO"  "NO"  "YES"
 [3,] "NO"  "NO"  "NO" 
 [4,] "NO"  "YES" "NO" 
 [5,] "NO"  "YES" "NO" 
 [6,] "NO"  "YES" "NO" 
 [7,] "NO"  "NO"  "NO" 
 [8,] "YES" "YES" "NO" 
 [9,] "YES" "YES" "NO" 
[10,] "NO"  "YES" "NO"
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**
After the helpful notes of Jean-Claude Arbaut, ThomasIsCoding and GuedesBF please note that the first answer is wrong, here is an alternative with `dplyr`:

We could use `across` after changing `matrix` to `tibble` class and rechange to `matrix` after our operation:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

MAT <- MAT %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(. > 5, "YES", "NO"))) %>% 
  as.matrix()
```

**First answer: Warning!**

**Do not use this code**

```
MAT[MAT>5] <- "yes"
MAT[MAT<=5] <- "no"
```

as Jean-Claude Arbaut, ThomasIsCoding and GuedesBF indicated, it will coerce to character after the first assignment, which could lead to unexpected outcomes in downstream operations.

Comment: Highly buggy code. Note that after the first instruction, MAT is a character matrix. Then, for instance, `"6e-12" <= 5` is false. Even if you don't change the type inadvertently, it's dangereous to write it this way. Replace "yes" with 1 and "no" with 0 and it fails again.

Comment: This will coerce to character after the first assignment, which could lead to unexpected outcomes in dowstream operations as observed by @Jean-ClaudeArbaut and ThomasIsCoding

Comment: Thank you all for your input. I have updated my answer. Please tell me if I should delete the answer or maybe leave it to have an inverse learning effect.