# Reading a csv file as matrix and change the entries using conditional if in R

Tags: r, csv, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have the csv file and I want to read it as a dataframe or matrix. I successfully read the .csv file, but when I want to change the entries based on conditional if statement, it does not work.
The csv file can be downloaded here [mydata](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hhbdqnahordxm8s/mydata.csv?dl=0)

I want to read this .csv file as a matrix or dataframe. Then, I want to change the entries to "YES" or "NO" based on some condition. I tried this:

```
mydata = read.csv("mydata.csv")
mydata = data.frame(mydata)
ifelse(mydata>0.005, "YES", "NO")
mydata
```

However, the result I got are
[image: output1]
and
[image: output2]

I have tried this

```
mydata = 
read.csv("/home/hudamoh/scRNAspatial/binomial/tangram_output.csv")
myresult = data.frame(mydata)
myresult[myresult>0.0005] <- "YES"
myresult[myresult<=0.0005] <- "NO"
myresult
```

But the output I got is that some are not changed to "YES" or "NO". Also I want it looks like matrix where the rows should be 0, 1, 9. Please help.
[image: myresult]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second case, the logical matrix should be created before updating i.e.

```
i1 <- myresult>0.0005
```

Once we update to 'YES', its type changes to `character` and thus when we do the second time, it won't work.  Also, it is better not to do the same step twice, instead do this once, store as an object and keep using it i.e. in the second case, we just need to negate (`!`) so that `TRUE -> FALSE` and `FALSE -> TRUE`

```
myresult[i1] <- "YES"
myresult[!i1] <- "NO"
```

---

In the first case with `ifelse`, the issue is that `ifelse` is applied on a logical 'matrix' as the 'test', and it returns a `vector` while stripping off the `dim` attributes.  In order to preserve the `dim` attributes, we can use `[]` while assignment

```
mydata[] <- ifelse(mydata > 0.005, "YES", "NO")
```

Comment: I see. yeah I got the idea. I applied it and it works.

Comment: do you know why when I applied this code inside the r function I made the output is totally wrong? it looks like the first picture I attached.

Comment: @MKHuda. It is because of the structure is not maintained when you are assigning a vector output to the same object.  It is maintained with `[]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
myresult <- as.data.frame(lapply(mydata, function(v) ifelse(v > 0.005, "YES", "NO")))
```

Note that here `mydata` is not an array but a dataframe, i.e. a list of vectors, with the `data.frame` class. The above applies the `ifelse` to each column.

Alternately, it's also possible to apply `ifelse` to the whole dataframe at once. However the result is not a dataframe but a matrix: the dataframe is first converted to matrix in order to be able to apply `ifelse` to the vector of all matrix elements, which you can't do directly with a dataframe. You can then convert the result back to a dataframe:

```
myresult <- as.data.frame(ifelse(mydata > 0.0005, "YES", "NO"))
```

Note that your dataframe has 3468 columns. The `read.csv` function assumes by default that the first row contains variable names. Since they are numbers, R prepends an X, hence thos strange Xnnnn appearing. If the first row contains data, pass an option:

```
read.csv("mydata.csv", header = F)
```

The variable names are then V1, V2... V3468.

Comment: I tried it and indeed it shows the variable names are V1, ..., V3467. It still shows the wrong result tho. What I actually want is a result where the row names are 0, 1, ..., 9 and the column names are 0, 2, ..., 3467 like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/2zzm7ku7uizv8f6/result.png?dl=0 but with entries are YES or No based on that condition mentioned. I still do not understand why it does not work when I run the code inside my R function.

Comment: What do you mean by the first row contains variable names? Did you mean the first column?

Comment: @MKHuda No, I meant row. The first row of the CSV file contains the variable names, i.e. the names of the columns. But you may transpose your dataframe after reading it with read.csv, if it's needed. As is, you have 11 rows in the CSV file, and the first is for variable names, hence 10 rows of data, and 3468 columns. What do you want **exactly**?

Comment: @MKHuda Note also that, while it's possible to have variable names (i.e. column names) that are (the string representations of) integers, by default read.csv prepends an X, because manipulating those variable names is not practical (you have to use backquotes everywhere).

Comment: @Jean_Claude I want the output is a dataframe where the rows are (10 rows) 0, 1, ..., 9 and the column names are 0, 1, ..., 3467 looks like the picture on the link dropbox above, but changing the entries to YES or NO. When I applied the codes independently, I got the output correctly but when I applied it inside the R function I made, it does not work

Comment: @MKHuda What's your function, then? I can't help you point out an error in your code if you don't show it. Regarding the column names, it's not difficult to change them to remove the X, but as I said, it's going to be more difficult to handle afterwards. Why not use column indices instead?

Comment: I do not know how to upload and make the function reproducible here since it requires many specific package dependencies from python and R. My function is reading the python script where the python script will do the analysing data and will result the out put in .csv file. Then inside the function there are the codes to read the .csv file and apply the if condition to change the entries to YES or NO as we discussed.

Comment: @MKHuda Are you using R only to change the output of a Python script? Why not do this in Python then? Anyway, post something, it sounds so weird I suspect there may be many problems here.

Comment: I am using R to create the Seurat object and the anndata. Also, I am using R to chcange the output as well from the python script. I am using the python since the specific method I read on the paper is applied in Python. Thus, I am combining using the python and the R. Any suggestions?

Comment: I cannot share it unfortunately. I think I solve it now, basically using the codes look like you suggested